# How to interface an Ionic SPV bitcoin wallet to blockchain nodes?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, bitcoin, blockchain

To further extend my understanding of bitcoin I would like to try and build my own SPV-based wallet using the Ionic] (cordova) mobile app framework (hybrid-app).

Using the browserified version of [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) I have managed to implement all the key generation schemes for a hierarchical deterministic wallet (as described in BIP32) following the BIP44 guidelines.

At this point I am however stuck as to how one would go about implementing the communication with full nodes in the network using bloomfilters as described in [BIP37](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0037.mediawiki) from within a hybrid app. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how this could best be implemented.

Also some concrete questions that might help me in the right direction:

- Do all full nodes handle bloomfilters sent by SPV clients?
- How would one connect to a bitcoin node from a cordova app? (if I'm not mistaken one will have to connect to a TCP socket of the node)

Any help would be of course greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you get any idea on how to do it? Can you share it?

Comment: https://github.com/lightninglabs/neutrino – here is Go implementation, relying on Compact Filters, which are less demanding and more secure than Bloom Filters. It can be compiled under go-mobile. Currently, it's under development, and in alpha mode. If that's not enough, I can find some more links and post as a full answer.